# "Index was outside the bounds of the array" when accessing variable

Tags: vb.net

Trying to make it where, you click a button, it lets you pick a directory, the directory, and then that directory, .file, is changed by the specific line. Current code. Sorry i'm a noob.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dialog As New OpenFileDialog()
    If DialogResult.OK = dialog.ShowDialog Then
        TextBox1.Text = dialog.FileName
        Dim Directory1 As String
        Directory1 = Trim(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim Item1 As String
        Item1 = Trim(TextBox2.Text)
        Dim thefile As String = Directory1
        Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Directory1)
        // This gets the error. Item1.
        // {"Index was outside the bounds of the array."}
        lines(2) = Item1

        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(thefile, lines)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure your file contains more than 2 line . If you debug you will get the issue.

Comment: If you want to add lines in case of a too short file, put `If lines.Count < 3 Then Redim Preserve lines(2)` where your comments currently are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the file is not allocating enough lines on the array `lines()`, probably because `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Directory1)` is reading less than three lines. Try using a file with more than 3 lines and it should work.

You could also do something like this (sorry, I'm no vb.net coder so my syntax could be wrong):

```
If lines.Length < 3 Then
   ReDim Preserve lines(2)
End If
lines(2) = Item1
```

I'm not exactly sure what do you want to achieve with this so I can't give a "solution". This would be just a "patch" to make your code work.

## Update

From requirements in the comments, if you want the line to be changed in a variable (which would be in `TextBox3.Text`, starting from zero), you'd need to do this:

```
Dim LineToBeChanged As Integer = Convert.toInt32(TextBox3.Text)
If lines.Length < LineToBeChanged+1 Then
   ReDim Preserve lines(LineToBeChanged)
End If
lines(LineToBeChanged) = Item1
```

Comment: @Jens sorry, thought it would allocate 'n' number of items with index 0. As I said, I'm no vb.net coder :-) Edited

Comment: Sorry. So what I want it to do. I click a button, it pops up explorer where I choose a file. I want to edit a FILENAME.file, but it won't work. So i tried a text and it DID work, but edited line 3 instead of line 2, like I want it to. This of course is just a test, for a project I want to do later.

Comment: @DylanGM the code I posted would allocate 3 items in the array lines() in case the read file was too short (preserving the original data)... in case the file had more than 3 lines, it doesn't do anything since the original code would work.

Comment: I have no clue how to post the code correctly so it's making it difficult.
`code`Test`code`

Comment: I don't understand. If you have specific requirements, please edit your question. When asking something, understand that we do not know your program, and we have only read exactly what you have written in your question. We don't even know there'd be a `TextBox3` in your code and we don't know what your program does, other than by the code you have posted.

Comment: Ah, after your edit, I understand. I'm not sure if `vb` translates strings to numbers, but I'm pretty sure  you can't use a string to redimension an array, it'd need to be an `Integer`.

Comment: @DylanGM See my edit, and check if that's what you want

Comment: Alright! I finally figured out how to post code XD. So my program is a TEST for a later project I want to make, but I need to make sure I can do what I want to do first. This is a basic program. currently, with 3 Textboxs. And a button.

I'm trying to make it where you can type in textbox2 what you want to replace the line with. Then textbox3 will define what line you are replacing, and finally you click the button, you pick the .file you want to edit, it will edit it, and then show the Directory of the file you edited in textbox1.

Comment: This works kinda. The original file has 2 lines. It turns it into a file with 4 lines, and the 3rd line is the line that gets edited. Now trying your new code. One sec.

Comment: That's what your code was originally doing: `lines(2) = Item` means "replace the line in the third index by the contents of item", since indices start with zero (so lines(2) is the third line)

Comment: Perfect! You helped me out so much. I'm using Notepad ++ so I was going off of how they numbered there lines. I wasn't thinking about the line 0. It works perfectly now. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: If the answer helped, please mark it as an answer (using the tick mark) so others would know the original question was already answered :-)

Comment: As an additional comment (not related to the problem in the question) and a general recommendation, try to name your variables correctly. It'll help you get back to the code in a few months and still understand it: `TextBox1` doesn't say anything (you could name it `FilePathTextBox`, for example), `Directory1` is misleading (you are storing the file path, not a directory), and `dialog` could be named `FileNameDialog`. Also, try to be consistent with the casing: if you have `Directory1` and  `TextBox`, then `thefile` should be `TheFile`. It takes some initial effort, but it definitely pays